# Using COM to open Word

Tags: php, com, word-2007

I am actually trying some codes i found from http://php.net/manual/en/class.com.php

```
  <?php
    // starting word
    $word = new COM("word.application") or die("Unable to instantiate Word");
    echo "Loaded Word, version {$word->Version}\n";

    //bring it to front
    $word->Visible = 1;

    //open an empty document
    $word->Documents->Add();

    //do some weird stuff
    $word->Selection->TypeText("This is a test...");
    $word->Documents[1]->SaveAs("Useless test.doc");


    //closing word
    $word->Quit();

    //free the object
    $word = null;
    ?>
```

But this does not seem to work. I am using Word 2007 and i get the following:

Loaded Word, version 12.0 
Fatal error: Call to undefined method variant::SaveAs() in C:\xampp\htdocs\final\testq.php on line 14

Can anyone solve this problem? Is it because i am using Word 2007?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by using : http://www.phpbuilder.net/columns/venkatesan20030501.php3?
Thanks for your replies

Answer (score 1):

The `Documents` object is a Collection object, not an array.  Try:

```
$word->Documents(1)->SaveAs("Useless test.doc");
```

Or

```
$word->ActiveDocument->SaveAs("Useless test.doc");
```

Comment: @chupinette: try `$word->ActiveDocument->SaveAs("Useless test.doc");`

Answer (score 1):

Your sample runs fine for me, both with Word 2003 and Word 2007 on Window 7. Therefore I assume that the problem might be an incorrectly installed/configured Word. For troubleshooting do the following:

- repair the Word installation
- make sure Word has been started at least once as the same user your script runs under
- disable all add-ins
- go to `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Templates\` and rename the Normal.dot(x) file
- make sure that you actually have permissions to save files to the specified location, try with an absolute path

Comment: How do i disable all add ins?I have found the Normal file which is a macro enabled template. To which name should i rename it? thanks for your help

Comment: Just backup the Normal.dot(x) or delete it. You can disable the add-ins one-by-one via Office button -> Word Options -> Add-ins, then select add-in type from the combo box and press Go...

Comment: PHP 5.3.1 and im using Windows Vista

Comment: I did my test on 5.3.2 on Windows 7 in case it matters.

Comment: Do you suggest that i switch to 5.3.2?